# What is the significance of a self executing anonymous function with three arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I see some iteration of ~~

```
;(function (window, Extensions, undefined){ --contents of a file-- });
```

Is there some pattern that calls the three variables of environment, wrapper, and error?

I don't understand this and would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me. I apologize for the brevity of the question. I don't completely know how to reference this.

Comment: It's *"self executing"*, nothing else ie executing it. The point of it is to execute immediately, creating a private scope within it that doesn't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: That function you posted isn't even self-executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous function is defined with three arguments, but usually only invoked with two parameters.

In the case of `undefined`, this ensures that the value is truly undefined, as in previous versions of JavaScript this kind of statement was legal: `undefined = true;`.

For the other parameters, this technique may be used to abbreviate long names (as in `jQuery` to `$`) or provide a way for code minification to shorten global variables (like window).

Comment: Thank you. This makes much more sense.